# Bar plot for a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I want to create a bar plot only for column "Cluster" which would show how many occurrences are present for each cluster in the data frame and add different color to each Cluster (each Bar)

**Dummy Data:**

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'col1': ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Agree', 'Agree', 'Disagree'],
        'col2': ['Agree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Agree', np.nan , 'Disagree'],
        'col2': ['Agree', 'Agree', 'Agree', 'Agree', 'Disagree', np.nan],
        'Cluster': ['Cluster 1', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 2', 'Cluster 1', 'Cluster 3', 'Cluster3']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: yes I did. I could not add colors for each bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c = ['red', 'yellow', 'black', 'blue']
cluster_counts = df.Cluster.value_counts()
plt.bar(cluster_counts.keys(), cluster_counts.values, color=c)
plt.show()
```

Hope this helps.